# How can i transfer a temporary Taken image uri into and permanent uri to store it in a server ? REACT NATIVE

Tags: firebase, react-native, server, expo, uri

i started working with expo image picker and before i was storing the uri of the image in the FileSystem.documentDirectory from expo-file-system , that would store it in the phone , but now i want to store it on my database server (firebase) i don't know how to transfer it to a permanent uri ? how can i manage that ?

this the temporary uri that i got after taking the image : file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fshop-8054a9d3-c78c-47df-81bd-20de56fa4bd4/ImagePicker/5a4bab1f-8f7c-4ffa-ad42-f04ea740e429.jpg

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#upload-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Firebase'Storage accepts BLOB data for file upload.

Fetch and upload BLOB data to cloud storage

```js
  const imgRef = firebase.storage().ref("images/filename.jpg");
  const metadata = { contentType: "image/jpg" };

const localPath="file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fshop-8054a9d3-c78c-47df-81bd-20de56fa4bd4/ImagePicker/5a4bab1f-8f7c-4ffa-ad42-f04ea740e429.jpg"

const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", localPath, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

// Firebase API should change while you're working with Firebase V9
 await imgRef.put(blob, metadata);

  // We're done with the blob, close and release it
  blob.close();
```

Comment: can you please explain to me the first part of ref and where will it transfer it to a permanent uri ? sorry im a beginner

Comment: I was referring to Firebase storage - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#web-version-8

Comment: i did what you told me and after i initializeApp(firebaseConfig) i get this error [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No Storage Bucket defined in Firebase Options.] even tho i have the storage bucket defined in my firebaseConfig